# CKEDITOR in chrome adding "?" mark at cursor position while apply any style(bold/italic) without selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, styles, ckeditor

I have a page which has CKEDITOR.when i try to apply any style(no selection made just i clicked inside the editor) within the editor, it is working in all other browser except chrome.

> **Chrome adding "?" mark at the cursor position.**

is this ckeditor bug?

i try to find 
`addCommand("bold")`/`addCommand("strong")` function but its not found.

chrome add "?" mark like below:

```
<strong>?</strong>
```

can i solve that issue?

Please help me out this issue.

Comment: please check in ckeditor forums..

Comment: I'm using it in chrome and works perfectly fine. What is your chrome version?

Comment: Chrome Version 29.0.1547.76 m CKEDITOR version 4.0

Comment: Are you sure that your server sends files in UTF-8 encoding and that your page uses it too? Very similar to http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10919

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem but i solved by made some changes in ckeditor.js

```
if(!!g[0]&& g[0].startOffset!= g[0].endOffset){
     a.selectRanges(g);c.removeCustomData("doc_processing_style");
 }
```

**added if condition before selectRange.**

Comment: That helped, thanks! As the variables might be named differently, just look for `removeCustomData("doc_processing_style")` in your minified ckeditor.js to find the line you need to change. After adding the proposed `if` statement, style changes without a selection will be dismissed from now on.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue with ckeditor. I have fixed issue by replacing special character with empty string.

How I solved the issue is as follow:

1. I beautified the ckeditor minified file using jsbeautifier.org
2. after beautified file, I found the function where hrml is parsed. Below is the function. (search for "htmlParser.text.prototype" in your file)

   `a.htmlParser.text.prototype = {
           type: 3,
           writeHtml: function(l, m) {
               var n = this.value;
               if (m && !(n = m.onText(n, this))) return;
               l.text(n);
           }
       };`
3. I have replaced the line from above function

   ```
       var n = this.value;
   ```

with

```
        var n = this.value.replace(/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/g, '');
```

This line replaces the special character with empty. This solved my issue. This might be a hack but it worked for me.

Hope this saves somebody's time.

Note: To keep file minified, search for the exact code without beatifying file and add your code.

Thanks

Comment: Does a "special character" mean everything outside the 95 characters in the printable ASCII range?  What happens to unicode characters?

Answer (score 0):

It is asked before on CKEditor forums. You can find it here: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Question-Mark-after-pressing-button-toolbar
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Please find out the below code in ckeditor.js file.

```js
CKEDITOR.tools.repeat
```

You will found there '?' repetition count like this

```js
CKEDITOR.tools.repeat("?",7)
```

it could be 7 or other value in your case.

Solution: Please make this value '0'. It will work defiantly.